# Scala - Converting RDD to map

Tags: scala

I am a beginner in scala.

I have a class User containing a `userId` as one of the attributes.
I would like to convert RDD of users to a map with the `userId` as key and `user` as value.

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a RDD with the pairs (`userId`, `user`) and then convert it to Map after

Comment: Thanks this is helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let suppose you have the RDD `myUsers:RDD[Users]`. Each record of the RDD contains the attributes `userId`. You can transform it into a `newRdd` this way:

```
val newRdd = myUsers.map(x => (x.userId, x))
```

If You want to convert `newRdd` to a Map:

```
val myMap = newRdd.toMap
```

*You can do these two computations in one line, I splitted them just for explanation*